# VBA issue when reopening a form

Tags: vba

I am creating a user interface with VBA and have an issue when I close a form with the `X` button.

1. A main window has several buttons; one of them call a form for the user to identify. The code, very simple, is below:

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
       Main_Form.Hide
       Identification_Form.Show
   End Sub
   ```
2. Then the Identification form opens; It has a textbox in which the user enters his name and a `OK` button to validate and follow the process.
   Yet I want the user to be able to close this window with the `X` button and go back to the main form.
   The code is below:

   ```
   Public how_closing As Integer

   Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
       If how_closing = 0 Then
           Main_Form.Show
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
       how_closing = 0
   End Sub

   Private Sub OK_Id_Click()
       If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter your name."
           Exit Sub
       End If
       user_name = TextBox1.Text
       how_closing = 1
       Unload Identification_Form
       Third_Form.Show
   End Sub
   ```

   The `how_closing` variable is used to know if the unloading of the form is due to the press of the `OK` button or the `X` button (the behaviour should not be the same of course).

My issue is the following:
If I launch the identification a first time, everything works fine. But if I close it (`X` button) and then relaunch it, nothing works; the `OK` button doesn't react, neither does the `X` button. All I can do is stop all the `macros`.

Have you ever seen this kind of bug ?

Comment: See this: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: @KostasK. Ok thank you for the link, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options :

Answer 1 (the quick way) - Just add this to your code and live further:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    End
End Sub
```

---

Answer 2 (the tough way, which would need about 2 months to learn some OOP basics):

- Read about OOP
- Rebuild the form, following the good practices, defining the form as an object and not working with the default instance:

  - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154401/handling-dialog-closure-in-a-vba-user-form
  - http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/ (disclaimer - my site)
- Enjoy

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.
Yet the quick answer does not really do what I want since it closes everything when I press the 'X' button...
I guess I have to think about OOP then.
Thanks